# Write multiple objects to a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple objects created from my class and would like to write each of them to an individual row in a CSV file.

This is an example of how my code would look.

```
p1 = Person("name1", "first", 2.5, 0.5, 3.6)
p2 = Person("name2", "second", 0.6, 5, 3)
p3 = Person("name3", "third", 1, 0.5, 3.4)
p4 = Person("name4", "fourth", 1.4, 0.3, 3.2)
```

So I would like all the info for a person to be stored in a CSV file to look like this:

```
name1 first 2.5 0.5 3.6
name2 second 0.6 5 3
```

etc.

I know how to write csv's in general using the csv import, just not with data like this.

Person Class:

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, name, number, score1, score2, score3):
        self.name = name 
        self.number = number
        self.score1 = score1
        self.score2 = score2
        self.score3 = score3
```

Comment: What is the structure of the Person() class? You need to extract the relevant attributes for the class and then write each to the CSV. You may get a dict of the attributes of an instance by calling <object>.__dict__ (aka p1.__dict__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fields of an instance as a `dict` by using `vars`:

```
>>> Person("name1", "first", 2.5, 0.5, 3.6)
{'name': 'name1', 'first_name': 'first', 'a': 2.5, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 3.6}
```

This allows to use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write columns in a predictable way:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'first_name', 'a', 'b', 'c']  # adjust this to your class' fields
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(vars(p1))
    writer.writerow(vars(p2))
    writer.writerow(vars(p3))
    writer.writerow(vars(p4))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! This was what I was looking for. Is it also possible to select only certain elements of the object, say the name and one of the scores, and put that into the csv?

Comment: @Jimmy Just exclude them from ``fieldnames`` and pass ``extrasaction='ignore'`` to the ``csv.DictWriter``. See the documentation of the ``DictWriter`` for details.